# Question about finite functinos in Rockafellar

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis

In the famous book "Convex Analysis" by R.T. Rockafellar, we have the following Corollary (10.1.1):

> A convex function $f$ finite on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is necessarily continuous.

What is the exact definition of finite here? I can't find it in the book. Is there  a general definition of finiteness in the sense of convex analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, convex functions are allowed to attain the value $+\infty$. For example,
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \|x\|^2 \quad &\text{if } \  \|x\|\le 1 \\ +\infty \quad &\text{if }\ \|x\|> 1\end{cases} $$ is a convex function on $\mathbb R^n$. Requiring $f$ to be finite on $\mathbb R^n$  means that $f(x)$ is a finite number for every $x\in \mathbb R^n$, i.e., $f$ never attains $+\infty$.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. So if I have a map $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ which is convex. Is it then continuous?